# Why are my CSS Keyframe animations not working in Chrome? They are working in FireFox

Tags: google-chrome, animation, webkit, keyframe

My CSS @Keyframe animations are working in FireFox, however, even with
-webkit-animations and -webkit-keyframes they are not working in Chrome, what am I doing wrong?

Here is a codepen for easy viewing of the code: https://codepen.io/jmitchelreed/pen/vYXzMgv

```
    @keyframes yinLoop {
    from {
        rotate: 0deg;
    }
    to {
        rotate: 360deg;
    }
};

@-webkit-keyframes yinLoop {
    from {
        rotate: 0deg;
    }
    to {
        rotate: 360deg;
    }
};

img {
    width: 20%;
    animation: yinLoop 7s infinite linear;
   -webkit-animation: yinLoop 7s infinite linear;
}
```